# Inactive checkboxes on OS X 10.10 and Qt 5.3

Tags: macos, qt, osx-yosemite

On OS X 10.10 the checkbox becomes inactive while parent widget haven't focus.

Is this problem solved in Qt 5.4? Or need to use extra attributes for widgets on OS X 10.10.

Example:

[image: inactive]
[image: active]

I saw such problem even in Qt Creator. But can't find any similar issues in web.

STEPS TO REPRODUCE (Qt Creator 3.1.1)

1. Create simple project for Dialog window.
2. Add to the *.ui file QLineEdit, QListWidjet and layout without any
   modifications.
3. Code to add list items in the constructor of the dialog window:

   ```
   QListWidget* list = ui->listWidget;
   for( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
   {
       QListWidgetItem* item = new QListWidgetItem( "test" );
       item->setCheckState( Qt::Checked );

       list->addItem( item );
   }
   ```

Comment: Could you add your example code in order to reproduce the behavior?

Comment: @Simon Warta - added

Comment: There were some fixes in 5.4, related to OS X GUI. I'm not sure, didn't checked your issue.